# Why do I get error when I use forwardRef in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-ref, react-forwardref

I just try to understand how to use this property.

In my main file, I added these:

```
import Audio from "../../../src/Audio";

const audioRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(()=> {
    audioRef.current.play();
  }, [])
```

under return:

```
<View>         
    <Audio ref={audioRef} />    
</View>
```

And here is Audio.js

```
import React from "react";
import Song from "./components/song/song.mp3";

const Audio = React.forwardRef((props,ref) => {

  return(
    <audio src={Song} ref={ref}></audio>
  )
})

export default Audio;
```

here is the error,

[image]

Comment: The UI needs to render once for the React ref to have an attached HTMLDOMNode to access.

Comment: So what does it mean Sir, what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It means you need an additional render cycle *before* the ref is defined and attached to the DOMNode to call the `play` function of. You can add a "initialRender" state and trigger the effect on the second render.

```
const audioRef = useRef(null);

const [initialRender, setInitialRender] = useState(true);

useEffect(() => {
  setInitialRender(false);
}, []);

useEffect(()=> {
  if (!initialRender) {
    audioRef.current.play();
  }
}, [initialRender]);
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, but still gives the same error.

Comment: I guess react-native doesnt support "audio" itself, it gives this error

Comment: Oh, right, you're in React-Native. Yeah, seems you need a 3rd-party package for adding sound to a RN project. [react-native-sound](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sound) seems popular.

Comment: You may still need to forward a ref if you are trying to start an audio file from a parent component, and in this case you may want to take a peek at the [useImperativeHandle](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle) React hook.

Answer (score 0):

You should receive the error as you might violating the rules for react component.

as in the Audio component, you are using another component that start's with audio which starts with the small case as you should have to use the component name that starts with a capital letter.

Have a look at the error code.

```
const Audio = React.forwardRef((props,ref) => {

  return(
    // error is here component name must starts with a capital letter
    <audio src={Song} ref={ref}></audio>
  )
})
```

Comment: Yes, but if i write it as Audio, it still gives an error. I think its because react-native doesnt support audio component, so if i want to use it i have to import third party. Thank you for replying

Comment: Yes, there is no built-in component available for Audio in react-native you should have to install the third-party library or you do have to make your own audio native module.